# GAE datastore data lost

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I'm running a GAE java project for almost 3 years, it's a blog like app, with almost 100k users, but every now and then people report their data lost. say, they found their blogs from June to now is missing suddenly when they login the app one day, some people even claim all their data has lost, and some just lost the blog they are working on yesterday. From the backend datastore GQL result, the data is just vanish without any clue.

Even though this situation is very rare(less than 20 reports in this year), but it did happen and has very bad result.

In summary, the problem is user data is stored in Google Datastore for a while, but one day they just vanish and can not be queried though GAE admin console GQL(and my app).

Does anybody come across the same problem like me? Any comments or suggestions are appreciated. My app is billing enabled through the Admin Console.

Comment: very very unlikely to be a google bug. most likely a bug in your code but we cant help you without you first investigating and showing us your investigation including code. you are likely deleting that data somehow. as it is we cant help.

Comment: Just want to +1 the above comment. This is 99.999% certainly a bug in your code. Look closely at code that /changes/ data - it might not look like an explicit delete. It could be a problem as simple as orphaning some pointers; there are no referential integrity checks in the datastore.